# Why does traceroute shows multiple paths but mtr does not?

Tags: unix, traceroute

I know networks use multiple paths; they show up in traceroute, but not in mtr.  Is mtr somehow sticking to the first path?  What is it dong?

```
$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.210.46), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (172.16.9.1)  1.303 ms  1.332 ms  1.421 ms
 2  host-92-31-0-1.as13285.net (92.31.0.1)  14.965 ms  15.810 ms  16.978 ms
 3  xe-11-2-0-bragg001.bre.as13285.net (78.151.225.39)  19.456 ms  20.785 ms  23.052 ms
 4  host-78-151-225-14.static.as13285.net (78.151.225.14)  24.255 ms host-78-151-229-20.as13285.net (78.151.229.20)  25.979 ms host-78-151-225-18.static.as13285.net (78.151.225.18)  27.059 ms
 5  host-78-144-8-57.as13285.net (78.144.8.57)  33.513 ms host-78-144-12-213.as13285.net (78.144.12.213)  35.825 ms host-78-144-10-37.as13285.net (78.144.10.37)  35.374 ms
 6  72.14.214.222 (72.14.214.222)  38.005 ms 72.14.242.127 (72.14.242.127)  35.820 ms 72.14.214.222 (72.14.214.222)  34.968 ms
 7  216.239.54.251 (216.239.54.251)  37.260 ms 64.233.174.83 (64.233.174.83)  22.876 ms 216.239.54.251 (216.239.54.251)  25.085 ms
 8  108.170.232.105 (108.170.232.105)  25.606 ms 108.170.232.103 (108.170.232.103)  27.050 ms  28.886 ms
 9  lhr25s11-in-f46.1e100.net (216.58.210.46)  29.601 ms  30.552 ms  31.896 ms
$ mtr --report google.com
Start: Wed Oct 26 11:07:33 2016
HOST: localhost.localdomain       Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- gateway                    0.0%    10    1.2   1.6   1.1   2.7   0.5
  2.|-- host-92-31-0-1.as13285.ne  0.0%    10   16.8  15.3  14.0  18.3   1.2
  3.|-- xe-11-2-0-bragg001.bre.as  0.0%    10   19.2  16.5  14.9  19.2   1.1
  4.|-- host-78-151-225-30.static  0.0%    10   16.3  16.2  15.7  16.6   0.0
  5.|-- host-78-144-12-147.as1328  0.0%    10   23.1  23.1  22.3  25.2   0.7
  6.|-- 72.14.242.127              0.0%    10   23.3  23.9  23.0  26.1   1.0
  7.|-- 216.239.54.251             0.0%    10   22.5  22.8  21.9  25.3   0.8
  8.|-- 108.170.232.105            0.0%    10   22.1  22.5  22.0  23.2   0.0
  9.|-- lhr25s11-in-f46.1e100.net  0.0%    10   23.3  23.4  22.7  24.3   0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the traceroute in modern Linux has options which match mtr behaviour (and vice versa).  We can see this is a matter of defaults only.

`traceroute` was the original.  The details of the original method can be inferred from the [documentation](http://tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/share/man/cat8/traceroute.0), but it wasn't considered necessary to spell it out.  Since Linux traceroute added multiple options, the differences are described.

> ### default
>
> The traditional, ancient method of tracerouting. Used by default.
>
> Probe packets are udp datagrams with so-called "unlikely" destination
>      ports.  The "unlikely" port of the first probe is 33434, **then for
>      each next probe it is incremented by one.**
>
> ### icmp
>
> Most usual method for now, which uses icmp echo packets for probes.
>     If you can ping(8) the destination host, icmp tracerouting is applicable as well.

`mtr`'s default appears to be icmp, the "most usual method for now".

## Conclusion

multipath routing is expected to keep packets from the same connection on the same path.  This avoids out-of-order delivery, which can be quite undesirable.  It does so by looking at the address and port of the source and destination.  (Together with the protocol.  These values are described as the "5-tuple").

`traceroute`'s default changes the UDP port for each probe, so they change paths.

`mtr`'s default uses ICMP echo, which does not have a port number and therefore its probes will all follow the same path.

If you request UDP or TCP traceroute in `mtr` then the different paths are shown.  There may be other differences compared to `traceroute`, but in this respect it happens to behave similarly.

---

## Sidetrack: why wasn't icmp used?

So Linux `traceroute` deliberately remains faithful to the original, including its choice of default mode.  But the reason for the original choice is not entirely clear.

I remembered reading `man tracepath`:

> commercial [IPv4] routers do not return enough information in icmp error messages. Probably, it will change, when they will be updated. For now [tracepath] uses Van Jacobson's trick, sweeping a range of UDP ports to maintain trace history.

however the point is that `tracepath` uses newer facilities to avoid requiring root privileges.  The issue referred to is that the ICMP error replies would not include any of the payload of a *UDP* packet.  Payload of an ICMP echo packet *would* be included (but generating such probes requires root).

> Traceroute varies (increments) the UDP destination port number for each probe sent out, in order to reliably match ICMP TTL Exceeded messages to individual probes. Because the UDP ports occur right after the IP header, they can be relied on to be included in the "original packet" portion of the ICMP TTL Exceeded messages, even though the ICMP standards only mandate that the first eight octets following the IP header of the original packet be included in ICMP messages (it is allowed to send more though).
>
> When ICMP ECHO requests are used, the probes can be disambiguated by using the sequence number field, which also happens to be located just before that 8-octet boundary.

[PERT](http://kb.pert.geant.net/PERTKB/VanJacobsonTraceroute) goes on to suggest

> It is believed that this is because at that time, some gateways (as routers were called then) refused to send ICMP (TTL exceeded) messages in response to ICMP messages, as specified in the introduction of RFC 792, "Internet Control Message Protocol". Therefore the UDP variant was more robust.

The [source code comments](http://tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/src/usr.sbin/traceroute/traceroute.c) explain the UDP port use as well, but not the use of UDP over ICMP echo.  A strict reading suggests one other possibility

> since icmp's aren't sent for icmp's

In context, the point is that icmp errors are never sent in response to an icmp *response*, in order to avoid an infinite cycle of responses.  It is certainly plausible that implementations would apply this to all icmp packets, instead of just responses.  The comments also mention various implementation bugs, which users had to bear in mind to interpret traceroute result.

However it's also possible Van Jacobson conflated the point himself.  One might simply have *assumed* that icmp errors would not be returned for any icmp packet, overlooking that this didn't necessarily apply to icmp echo requests.

> Don't use this as a coding example.  I was trying to find a
>   routing problem and this code sort-of popped out after 48 hours
>   without sleep.  I was amazed it ever compiled, much less ran.

Comment: The UDP packet gets sent towards the destination, beginning with a Time To LIve counter of 1, for the first 3 probes., 2 for the next triplet, and so-forth, until the above case's 30 hop max is reached, or the target host replies to the probe.

The first three packets go out with a TTL of 1.  The first router decrements the TTL counters to 0 on each and discards it, and if so inclined, sends an ICMP TTL Expired message back to the source.

The next 3 packets go out with a TTL of 2.  They make it past the first router, and get discarded at the 2nd hop, and so forth.

Comment: Traceroute is only reporting what the source IP of the router interface  that discarded its packets.  This seems to be multiple interfaces for a few of the hops in the example; perhaps because of per-packet load balancing across multi-link connections:  The round trip time grouping for those hops do not suggest that the paths are significantly different in length, line rate, or congestion.

Comment: if MTR is only sending out one discovery packet to find the path to www.google.com, it will only get one answer, and only ping that one host.

Comment: I refer you to the Snt column, also the existence of a non-zero StdDev column.  Note that the normal mode for mtr is to run continuously, updating using ncurses.  `--report` mode is useful for pasting like this, but it's a complete annoyance otherwise because it only prints the report when it's finished.

Comment: There isn't an ICMP-only method of finding a path between two hosts, because, as you correctly state, no ICMP errors are generated for an ICMP packet.  This suggests that if MTR is doing its thing via ICMP, it's using echo requests & replies based on a list it got from the ordinary traceroute method.

You could, of course, use tcpdump or another packet capture utility, and watch what MTR is doing.

Comment: No. I stated that no ICMP errors are generated for an ICMP response. Note that Windows tracert uses ICMP echo only. https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Wireshark/ICMP_Trace